# Why is using width:100% to make a table expand relatively to window size creates an undesired space?

Tags: css, width, css-tables

I'm trying to create a website that will adjust the size of table elements table cells relative to the size of the window, so that it will always fit inside the window. Here's what I have:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tablecell">
    <image src="fb.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tablecell">
    <image src="twitter.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tablecell">
    <image src="youtube.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tablecell">
    <image src="apple.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tablecell">
    <image src="email.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

What's messing this up is the `width:100%`. Here's a picture of the results. I circled the problem space in blue. Ignore Soulja Boy's face.

[image]

Basically I just want this centered correctly so that the YouTube image is in the middle of the page. The space created by using `width:100%` prevents that, but I want to use this or a similar property so that the table will always fit inside the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're just seeing the fact that the images are aligned to the left. Try **text-align:center;**, like this:

```
     .table {
         display:table;
         margin-right:auto;
         margin-left:auto;
         width:100%;
     }

     .tablecell {
         display:table-cell;
         text-align:center;
     }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q73LK/

**As a side note**, there is no need to use classes for the cells. You can do this instead:

```
     .table {
         display:table;
         margin-right:auto;
         margin-left:auto;
         width:100%;
     }

     .table div {
         display:table-cell;
         text-align:center;
     }
```

**As a second side note**, you are missing "alt" attribute on your images. For valid HTML, you need to include the "alt" attribute. Like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tablecell"><image alt="fb" src="fb.png"/></div>
    <div class="tablecell"><image alt="twitter" src="twitter.png"/></div>
    <div class="tablecell"><image alt="youtube" src="youtube.png"/></div>
    <div class="tablecell"><image alt="apple" src="apple.png"/></div>
    <div class="tablecell"><image alt="email" src="email.png"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no need to close an `<img>` tag in HTML5, `alt`attributes are still required however

Answer (score 2):

The divs are spaced correctly, but the images inside it are not.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/CzaK5/

Just add `text-align:center;` to the `.tablecell`.

**Edit**: Ryan Henderson beat me to it.